# UIButton doesn't show the full image inside the button

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to set the UIButton (width:55, height:55) with image size 55*55. But after I set the image, the button becomes this way

[image]

Which is smaller than the image size. I don't know how to make the image fill the button. Could anyone give me a hint? Or should I change to UIImageview instead?

Comment: try setting the *content mode to aspect fill or scale to fit* for Image of UIBUtton

Comment: image is 1x or 2x or 3x?

Comment: @Bilal It is 2x.

Comment: do you name the image file with suffix "@1x", "@2x", "@3x"?

Comment: In iOS, non-scalable graphics are defined in pixels while on-screen sizes are defined in points. 1 point * screen scale = pixels. The screen scale is dependent on the device. The simplest way to make any graphic fill its space is to set the content mode to aspect fill. This means it will completely fill the space will preserving the aspect ration of the asset. To ensure all assets are displayed correctly, provide an image for each scale (1x is practically unnecessary as those devices are obsolete). Alternatively, provide a scalable vector graphic in PDF form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image is 2x so that's way it's appearing small.

**Options 1**
Either you move it to 1x in your xcassets.

**Option 2**
If you want to keep it as 2x. You need high resolution image 110 x 110.

Comment: This isn't accurate.

Comment: You should provide an image at each scale factor, or use a vector graphic to ensure correct display.

Comment: I think my answer tries to explain why it's not appearing correctly. And is surely not inaccurate.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't fully explain why it's happening. The options are making the button half the size, or make source image twice as big. Putting the source image in the 1x spot results in bad on screen rendering unless it's being run on a non-retina device.

Answer (score 4):

Fill up the image like this:

```
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
myButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
```

Answer (score 2):

you can chnage content mode and then see.[image: chnage content mode and then see.]

Comment: I tried to change this setting but it doesn't work. It seems like the problem is that I put the image into 2x rather than 1x. Thanks!

Comment: yourbutton.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill // ALTERNATIVE:  .ScaleAspectFit

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/)

> iOS uses a coordinate system to place content onscreen. This coordinate system is based on measurements in points, which map to pixels in the display.

More from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)

> One point does not necessarily correspond to one physical pixel.

All image formats (PNG, JPG, etc) are sized using pixels. Your image is (55px, 55px) and you have placed it in the 2x scale factor location within the asset catalog. This is telling the system to interpret the image as if it were destined for a screen with a scale factor of 2x which means it's (27.5pt, 27.5pt).

You are specifying your button size in **points**. So you are putting a 27.5x27.5 image into a 55x55 button.

Moving the image to the 1x slot in the asset catalogue fixes your issue but sacrifices quality. Your designer's intention is going to be to make that image appear at a certain resolution. By using a (55px, 55px) asset in the 1x slot on a device with a 2x scale factor, you are halving the *intended* resolution of the image.

#### The correct solution for production iOS development:

The design team (this may be another person, or it may be you) should render all assets in 1x, 2x, and 3x scale factors. (For Android, these are referred to as hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi respectively plus Android supports several more scale factors)

You, the developer, should work exclusively in points when laying out your UI. If the image is supposed to be 55x55, you should get 3 images, 55x55px, 110x110px, and 165x165px. This will ensure that the image ***looks*** the same on all iOS devices.

#### The new way

A [more convenient way](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/) to handle the nightmare of different content scale factors was added in Xcode 7. You can provide a single vector graphic as a PDF and Xcode will do the rest for you. This has many benefits, including fewer files to manage. It also means that if Apple were to come out with a 4x scale factor device, all you would need to do is recompile your application.

Answer (score -1):

you can use image button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMiy5.png)

Comment: I did use this setting to set the image. But the size of the image is not what I expect.