# Why doesn't view change when I change bounds?

Tags: ios, uikit

If I change a UIView's bounds from...

```
v2.bounds = CGRect(0, 0, 70, 70)
```

to...

```
v2.bounds = CGRect(-2000, 0, 70, 70)
```

... nothing happens - the dimensions stay the same upon rendering. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help understand what bounds does, run this sample code in a view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let secondView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

newView.addSubview(secondView)


view.addSubview(newView)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {

    newView.bounds = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
}
```

Here we're moving the bounds to the right by 10 points, so you'll see the "second view" (which is red) move to the left by 10 points.

Changing the origin of the bounds changes the coordinate system of the view, which affects the location of all of it's subviews. It doesn't affect its origin with respect to its super view, however. For that, you should change the origin of the frame.

Comment: When it says, "x: 10", what is it ten of?

Comment: It is 10 points, I have an answer that discusses what points are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45083468/5099014). [This](http://iosres.com) is also useful (see logical resolution).

Comment: 10 points relative to it's origin within it's super view (i.e. frame.origin). If you look at a freshly created view, you'll see that the bounds.origin is always (0, 0).

Comment: So if the parent clip's bounds is moved to the right, why does the subview move to the left?

Comment: You're moving the origin of the bounds, but your reference frame is the overall view. You are essentially changing what the secondView's frame.origin _means_. The secondView's location starts as the newView.bounds.origin + secondView.frame.origin, which is (0-0, 0-0). When you change the bounds of newView, then secondView's location becomes (0-10, 0-0), which is (-10, 0).

Comment: Is the x and y of the bounds specifying the origin and not the top left coordinates of the view?

Comment: The x and y of the bounds is specifying the view's origin within its own coordinate system, which means if it's non-zero, then any subviews will be shifted. The x and y of the frame specify the view's origin within it's super view's coordinate system. It is all simply a mapping from different coordinate spaces. You should probably focus on the frame for now, since that is what you really need. The x and y of bounds do have a purpose, but it'll come up later as you get into more advanced view programming.

Answer (score 0):

Bounds only takes into account `width` and `height`, you are only changing the `origin` in your example, only changing `x` to be precise. To accomplish this use `frame` property:

```
v2.frame = CGRect(-2000, 0, 70, 70)
```

Comment: That's nuts. Why is the bounds a CGRect if it only sets width and height?

Comment: It is the rectangle on its own coordinate system, mainly for operations.
Here documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds